# sIFR 3 r436 unstable in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, sifr

I'm having an issue with my sIFR setup. It works perfectly in all other browsers than IE, and in IE it works most of the time, but usually not the first time you go into a page. You have to refresh is for it to work. 
When it doesn't work, it replaces the webtext with a blank area. 
Not using position: absolute anywhere, so it shouldn't have anything to do with that. 
And since it works, but is unstable, i'm even more at a loss.

Anybody experienced the same problems?

-seltar

Comment: Could you provide an example page?

Comment: I'm facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding a span inside the h1-element to be replaced, and linking to that instead